# Git How to discard changes to a submodule

Tags: git

I did some work in a git repository X, that has a submodule Y. I did some changes to files in X, which I want to keep and I did a change in the submodule Y that I want to discard now. So I want to discard all local changes I've made to the submodule.

I tried `git checkout -- ../dep/libY` but nothing changes.

Git status says:

```
modified:   ../dep/libY (modified content)
```

Comment: Are you executing it from the root of the checked out directory @Darragh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A submodule *is* a Git repository.  You may therefore `cd` into the submodule, and use `git reset --hard` to discard work done within the work-tree and index of that other Git repository.  (Be sure to run `git status` in that work-tree first, and other Git commands, if / as desired to make sure that any files you are discarding are truly unwanted.)

Comment: warning : if you have new commits instead of (modified content), it does the exact opposite of what you are trying to do :/

Answer (score 1):

In your checked out directory execute this command which will reset the files changed in that sub-directory to HEAD revision (in short it will discard your uncommitted changes in that submodule/subdirectory)

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/submodule
```

In your case the command would be:

```
git checkout HEAD -- ../dep/libY
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to undo the changes, git checkout submodule

```
git checkout dep/libY
```

**OR**

Go to the folder (for which you want to revert all changes) and execute

```
git checkout ./
```